# Guess the number sequence #2

Tags: number-sequence

What's the next number in the sequence and what is the link?

1 | 5 | 10 | 25 | 50 | 100 | 200 | 500 | 1000 | 2000 | 5000 | ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is

> 100000

because these are all

> currency denominations expressed in cents? 100000 = $1000 bill

That said, the one thing that is stumping me is that

> I would've thought the next numbers would have been 1000, 2000, 5000 instead of 10000, 20000, 50000 (in which case the next number should be 10000 = $100 bill).

Comment: You're absolutely right, sorry for the flaw, the right numbers were "1000", "2000" and "5000". The next bill is the 100$ Bill, 10000 expressed in cents.

Comment: I like how you think exactly like me. See you at my next quiz! :D

Comment: No worries on the error, it was still an understandable puzzle IMO! I think we're on quite a roll here -- 4 in a row for the two of us, we make quite the battery! See you soon! :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

> 100000000

Because

> The numbers of 0 are doubled every time it passes the 5*

Comment: Nice thought but no. (PS: i accidently made a mistake, it's updated now)